# How to play Enter the Matrix in multiplayer on the same computer?

Tags: pc, enter-the-matrix

I want to play Enter the Matrix with my brother on same computer.
I have a keyboard, mouse, and joypad.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The PC version of the game as no Multiplayer support. Thought if you have a good enough computer you can download a PS2 Emulator like [PCSX2](https://pcsx2.net) and a rom of the game to play it in multiplayer.

Once in the game go to the hacking system and enter *cheat.exe* then enter  *D5C55D1E* to unlock the mutiplayer mode.